# typescript how to find inside an array that is already in an array?

Tags: arrays, typescript, filter, find

I want to find a value inside an array that is already inside an array.

To give an example of my array:

```
[
    {
        ConcessionId: 1,
        ConcessionName: "Coyotes",
        KnownAs: [
          {
            TeamId: 1,
            Name: "Arizona Coyotes",
          },
          {
            TeamId: 2,
            Name: "Phoenix Coyotes",
          }
        ]
    },
    {
        ConcessionId: 2,
        ConcessionName: "Devils",
        KnownAs: [
          {
            TeamId: 3,
            Name: "Colorado Rockies",
          },
          {
            TeamId: 4,
            Name: "New-Jersey Devils",
          }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I want is when Icall my function it returns me the team name.
For example, I the parameter value is 3, I want Colorado Rockies as a name:

```
public getInfo(_TeamID) { 
    const concession: ConcessionInfo[] =  this.concessionList$.filter(function (x) {
      x.KnownAs.filter( (y)=> {
          y.TeamId= +_TeamID;
          return y.Name;
      })
    })

}
```

I try so many different way with filter. But never get something good. Never works.

I can make a double .foreach , for each array. but I think a better method exist than making a double loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `myArray` is contains the data you provided.

The following code will work if you're using Typescript 3.7 and above.

```
public getInfo(teamId: number): string | undefined {
    const team = this.concessionList$
      .map(concession => concession.KnownAs)
      .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])
      .find(team => team.TeamId === teamId)
    return team ? team.Name : undefined
}
```

Usage:

```
this.getInfo(3) // Colorado Rockies
```

Ok how this work?

You have to understand what is `find`. For example:

```
const result = [{name: 'foo', age: 1}, {name: 'bar', age: 2}]
    .find(people => people.name === 'foo')


console.log(result) // {name: 'foo', age: 1}
```

Comment: Man, your solution was what I was searching. Unfortunately, the flatmap was not working even if I add an import of mergemap. I also try to replace it with map. But after another error saying, team.TeamId was not recognize. Sad that you solution didn't work for me.

Comment: @baronming I've updated the solution to something that might be compatible with your Javascript version, do you want to try it out?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the filter method (which is in fact working similar as a for loop), you could do forEach on both arrays. For your current data structure, there is no other way around it.

```
getInfo = (_TeamID) => {
  let teamName = '';
  this.concessionList$.forEach(entry => {
    entry.KnownAs.forEach(team => {
      if(team.TeamId === _TeamID){
        teamName = team.Name;
        return; // break the loop.
      }
    })
  });
  return teamName;
}
```

Here is a working example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/double-for-lopp

EDIT
If you have a look at the polyfill implementation of filter from Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter which is in equivalent to the native implementation of filter, you can see that it is looping through the whole array, the same way as a forEach loop. The difference is that the filter method will return a new array based on the boolean condition inside the callback function, while a forEach loop does not return anything.

Comment: Yes, like I though, I need to use a double loop. It works great. thanks.